# How to implement dashed progress bar with antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

is there a way to create a dashed progress bar, something like attached with Ant Design. I've not seen any help on the Ant Design [documentation](https://ant.design/components/progress)

[image]